# Delete and Maintain Items on GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Sorry for the previous question I've posted. So here's my problem again, here's my code for the gridview.

`

```
    If e.CommandName = "DeleteItem" Then

        Dim gvItems As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
        Dim gvparent As GridViewRow = CType(gvItems.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        '(gvparent.Cells(2).Text)
        If gvItems.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            lblPopup.Text = "There must be atleast one row."
            mpeError.Show()
            Exit Sub

        End If

        Program.oEquipmentLoan.sTransactionCode = gvparent.Cells(3).Text
        'Dim gvItem As GridView = TryCast(gvitems.FindControl("gvItems"), GridView)
        'For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In gvitems.Rows
        '    Dim chkItem As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("chkSelectItems"), CheckBox)
        '    If (chkItem.Checked) Then

        '        Program.oEquipmentLoan.iItemNumber = gvRow.Cells(2).Text
        '        oSQLEquipmentLoan.DeleteEquipmentLoanItem(Program.oEquipmentLoan)

        '    End If
        'Next

        'loadGVGetTransactionLog()

        Dim icount As Integer = 0

        For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In gvItems.Rows

            Dim chkItem As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("chkSelectItems"), CheckBox)
            If (chkItem.Checked) Then
                icount += 1
            End If

        Next

        If icount > 0 Then

            For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In gvItems.Rows
                Dim chkItem As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvRow.FindControl("chkSelectItems"), CheckBox)
                If (chkItem.Checked) Then

                    Program.oEquipmentLoan.iItemNumber = gvRow.Cells(2).Text
                    oSQLEquipmentLoan.DeleteEquipmentLoanItem(Program.oEquipmentLoan)
                End If
            Next

        Else
            Dim gvr As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
            Dim Index As Integer = gvr.RowIndex
            Dim gvRowSelected As GridViewRow = gvItems.Rows(Index)

            Program.oEquipmentLoan.iItemNumber = gvRowSelected.Cells(2).Text
            oSQLEquipmentLoan.DeleteEquipmentLoanItem(Program.oEquipmentLoan)

        End If


    End If

    sIndex = gvTransactionLogViewer.PageIndex
    blnCount = True
    loadGVGetTransactionLog()

End Sub`
```

So, this code particularly deletes a selected row on a gridview. My problem is that whenever I delete an item, after it is deleted, I can't maintain to view the list.

**Image given Below :**

[image]

The photo shows on the before part is that when I'm selecting an item to delete. and on the after, when the item is deleted. And as you can see, what I need to maintain is the list of the updated items after I delete something and after it refreshes. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

on your .aspx page you need to do the partial postback to prevent the whole page postback.
you can achieve this using either asp.net ajax update panel "partial page rendering" or jquery.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that info @AliShahrokhi. But I'm not really good in ASP.NET and AJAX. This is like an assignment because I'm having my OJT so it's my first time to handle web development. Thanks! Anyway, I'll tell them about it! :)